# AngularJS resource - populate scope data inside controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a call to a restful service that I have and populate the data in my controller so that I can populate data on a JVector map. There is a good chance that I am taking the wrong approach (Should maybe be using directive).  I know that the service is working fine and I am getting the data back that I expect.  However, when I inspect the data within the json via console.log I am getting undefined.  I believe that it is because I am just getting a promise back and the data is not being actually populated until I would be displaying it on the page. I am most likely doing something wrong.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']).
        factory('mapDataSvc', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('api/sites', {});
        });
```

Controller:

```
var mapCtrl = function ($scope, mapDataSvc) {
    //http://coder1.com/articles/consuming-rest-services-angularjs
    $scope.mapData = {};

    mapDataSvc.query(function (response) {
        // Assign the response INSIDE the callback
        $scope.mapData = response;
    });

//I see the sites array in this log output
console.log($scope.mapData);

//This is showing undefined.
    console.log($scope.mapData.Sites);

}
```

Example JSON:

```
{
    Sites: [{
        VendorName: "MyVendor",
        SystemHardwareId: 111111,
        Longitude: 45.22,
        Longitude: -71.0418
    }]
}
```

Comment: You say "I see the sites array in this log output" in the comment. But you shouldn't see an array there, you should see a Sites property which holds an array. Can you clarify this point?

Comment: you are correct idursun....it is a Sites property that holds an array of data

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your console.log is executed before mapData is initialized inside mapDataSvc.query. Try to move it into mapDataSvc.query like this:

```
var mapCtrl = function ($scope, mapDataSvc) {
//http://coder1.com/articles/consuming-rest-services-angularjs
$scope.mapData = {};

mapDataSvc.query(function (response) {
    // Assign the response INSIDE the callback
    $scope.mapData = response;

   //I see the sites array in this log output
    console.log($scope.mapData);

   //Should be not undefined.
   console.log($scope.mapData.Sites);
});
```

}